# module.exports update value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, react-redux

Is it possible to update value of a module that has been exported.

For example:-
Colors.js

```
module.exports = {
   main: {
    primaryColor: 'red',
   },
   buttons: {
    backGround: 'blue',
   },
}
```

primaryColor and backGround are being used at several places (styled buttons, scss) in my application.
Based on certain events, I want to change primaryColor and backGround globally, such that it is applied to all the components where ever it is used.
Is there a way how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

It depends but generally yes. Every time you import the module every place that imports it gets the same **single** object. This is due to the module caching system. In effect this makes all modules singletons.

So every time you modify the value in any file all files will get the modified value. For example if you do:

```
colors.main.primaryColor = 'yellow';
```

It will change this value everywhere.

But weather or not this new value gets updated in your css/scss depends on how you set up your code to compile sass. If we are talking about javascript then yes, the values are *live* and will get the update. But for generated files like html, css, json, pdf, xml etc. it depends on when you generate those files.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I was able to change the color as mentioned in js the files. But however, it didn't update the values in my scss files. where I was using `sass::map`. Think I have to use sass `map.set` as specified here(https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map),  but  those are only recognised in scss files. These events happen in js files. so not sure how I can update or use sass map with in js. AnyIdea?

Comment: You need to understand your build process. Your  web browser cannot render scss files so at some point (usually at the beginning of running your program) your scss files gets compiled into css. If you want to regenerate your css files you need to do it manually and not using babel/webpack/babel etc. Also, your browser will usually load your css only once at the beginning of loading your page. Web browsers will not reload css files when the variable change. You need custom javascript to load the newly generated css files